# Convert Histogram to curve in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code

```
df1 = df['T1'].values

df1 = df1 [~np.isnan(df1 )].tolist()

plt.hist(df1 , bins='auto', range=(0,100))
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this graph

[image]

and this code

```
df2 = df['T2'].values

df2 = df2 [~np.isnan(df2 )].tolist()

plt.hist(df2 , bins='auto', range=(0,100))
plt.show()
```

which gives me this

[image]

Is there any way I can convert Histograms to Curves and then combine them together?

Something like this

[image]

Comment: histogram returns values `data = plt.hist(...)` and you can do `plt.plot(data[0])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly, you want to draw steps like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = np.random.rayleigh(30, size=9663)
d2 = np.random.rayleigh(46, size=8083)

plt.hist(d1 , bins=np.arange(100), histtype="step")
plt.hist(d2 , bins=np.arange(100), histtype="step")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.histogram`:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

chisq = np.random.chisquare(3, 1000)
norm = np.random.normal(10, 4, 1000)

chisq_counts, chisq_bins = np.histogram(chisq, 50)
norm_counts, norm_bins = np.histogram(norm, 50)

ax.plot(chisq_bins[:-1], chisq_counts)
ax.plot(norm_bins[:-1], norm_counts)

plt.show()
```

In the specific case of your data, which has outliers, we will need to *clip* it before plotting:

```
clipped_df1 = np.clip(df1, 0, 100)
clipped_df2 = np.clip(df2, 0, 100)

# continue plotting
```

[image]

Comment: Getting this error Out[77]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1b9ea4e0>

Comment: @asmgx it's not an error; you might just need to call `plt.show()` after that.

Comment: Thanks, Now it works for the example you posted but not for my data. the graph I get looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng416.png

Comment: @asmgx the reason for that is that you have some outliers in your data, which probably is why you passed `range=(0, 100)`. I will edit my code to rectify that.